# Determine all $2\times 2$ matrices of order $4$ up to similarity

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

I want to determine up to similarity all $2\times2$ matrices in $M_{2}(\mathbb{Q})$ and in $M_{2}({\mathbb{C}})$ of precise order 4. But since the minimal polynomial has to divide the polynomial $x^4-1$ and has at most degree 2 there are some possibilities for each field. But the matrices has precise order 4 so the minimal polynomial has to be $x^4-1$ but this is impossible! Any help will be great. thanks.

Comment: What is 'precise order'?

Comment: what do you mean precise order $4$ ?

Comment: this question is from Dummit's abstract algebra, I thought that it means the matrices has order 4 as the element of the groups $M_{2}(\mathbb{Q})$ and $M_{2}(\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: Why is that impossible??? Can you find a degree-2  polynomial that divides $x^4-1$ but doesn't divide $x^2-1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that (in the rational case) if the minimal polynomial is $x^2+1$ then it divides $x^4-1$ and yet the matrix has order exactly 4. In the complex case, same holds if the minimal polynomial is $x^2+1$ or $x+i$ or $x-i$ (in the latter cases, a factor of $x\pm1$ is optional). So, over the complex numbers, you're talking about similarity to one of $$\pmatrix{i&0\cr0&i\cr},\quad\pmatrix{i&0\cr0&-i\cr},\quad\pmatrix{-i&0\cr0&-i\cr},\quad\pmatrix{\pm i&0\cr0&\pm1\cr}$$ Over the rationals, think about a rotation through a right angle.

Comment: thank you very much for the solution. So all the rational matrices similar to the matrix $\ \left( \begin{array}{cc}
0 & -1  \\
1 & 0 
\end{array} \right)\ $?

Comment: Sorry but in the complex case what do you mean a factor of $x+1$ and $x-1$ is optional in the cases, since the minimal polynomial can not have that factors because of the order condition? So shouldn't we have the representative matrices$\ \left( \begin{array}{cc}
i& 0 \\
0 & i 
\end{array} \right)\ $,$\ \left( \begin{array}{cc}
-i & 0  \\
0 & -i 
\end{array} \right)\ $ and$\ \left( \begin{array}{cc}
0 & -1  \\
1 & 0 
\end{array} \right)\ $ for the minimal polynomials $x-i,\,\,x+i,\,\,x^2+1$ ,respectively?

Comment: If the minimal polynomial is, say, $(x-i)(x-1)$, then the matrix is similar to $\pmatrix{i&0\cr0&1\cr}$ and the matrix had order 4. Isn't that correct?

Comment: In fact i computed that before. But I figured out my mistake; we are assuming for all such matrices $x-1$ and $x+1$ are nonzero then add this two as a factor. Thanks..